# postDelayed() with messages Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I want my main UI thread to effectively "sleep" for 1 second before sending an empty message to a worker thread to perform some operation.

`Sleep()` is a problem for me because I cannot `quit()` the threads properly while it is performing `sleep()`, so I want to change it to `postDelayed(runnable r, long msDelay)` but it takes `runnable` object, not `Message`. How can I change this code? I am just passing empty message from main UI thread to worker thread.

UI thread:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    static Worker w1, w2;

 static Handler mainUIHandler = new Handler()
    {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            String sender = msg.getData().getString("SENDER");

            if (Objects.equals(sender, "CPU1")) 
            {
                mInfoTextView.setText("worker 1 thinking...");

                  //how to change the following 2 lines to postDelayed()?
                try{
                     Thread.sleep(1000);
                   } catch (Exception ignored) { }

                 w2.handler.sendMessage(w2.handler.obtainMessage());

            }
        }
    };
...
}
```

and the worker thread

```
 class Worker extends HandlerThread
    {
      ...

        Worker(String name)
        {
            super(name);
        }


        Handler handler= new Handler()
        {
            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg)
            {
                //perform work
                     Foo work = dowork();
               //communicate work to the UI thread to update the display
                Message message = MainActivity.mainUIHandler.obtainMessage();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("NAME", name);
                bundle.putInt("work", work);

                message.setData(bundle);

                MainActivity.mainUIHandler.sendMessage(message);
            }
        };

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            this.setName(WorkerThread.class.getName());
            this.setPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
        }
    }
```

I tried creating a new Runnable() and passing it to  postDelayed():

```
  w2.handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                            System.out.println("hello");
                        }
                    }, 1000);
```

but it's not triggering the handler in w2

Comment: I did this, but its not signaling the workers handler. -see bottom of OP

Comment: Anyone? I'm still stuck

Comment: have you seen `Handler.sendMessageDelayed()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can delay a `Message` with [`Handler.sendMessageDelayed()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageDelayed(android.os.Message,%20long)):

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // ...

    static Handler mainUIHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            // ...

            w2.handler.sendMessageDelayed(w2.handler.obtainMessage(), 1000);
        }
    }
}
```